# Converting mixed string to double

Tags: java

How to convert this string:

```
String str = "***123.45***";
```

to this double:

```
double d = 123.45;
```

When I use valueOf

```
double d = Double.valueOf("***123.04***");
```

or parseDouble

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("***123.45***");
```

it will throw `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""123.04""` because the string doesn't contain number only. I need to get rid of the asterisks.

Comment: Two questions: 1. Are there always 3 before and 3 after the double? And 2. Are they always `*`, or can it also be another character (like letters)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace api to replace all "*" in your input as below:

```
double d = Double.valueOf("***123.04***".replace("*", ""));
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: There is no need to use `replaceAll`, `replace` works too and OP doesn't have to care about escaping that asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

delete the asterixes before

```
str = str.replace("*", "");
```

Comment: This is not going to work unless and until you escape "*". you know wildcard character how they are :)?

Comment: `.replaceAll` uses a regex, so it should be either `str.replace("*", "");` or `str.replaceAll("\\*", "");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex to match the number:

```
String s = "eXamPLestring>1.4365345>>ReSTOfString";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\D*([0-9]*\\.*[0-9]*)\\D*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(m.group(1)));

}
```